# Convert string to executable code

Tags: string-manipulation

This is what I have done to turn the string to executable code.

```
st = "prime[m_]:=Module[{i=2},\[IndentingNewLine]For[,i<m,i++,If[Mod[\
m,i]\[Equal]0,Print[ToString@m<>" is not a Prime "];Break[]]];\
\[IndentingNewLine]If[i\[Equal]m,Print[ToString@m<>" is a Prime "]]\
\[IndentingNewLine]]"
ToExpression[st]
prime[29]
prime[30]
```

[image]
However, no success.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the internal quotation marks like so:

```
st = "prime[m_]:=Module[{i=2},\[IndentingNewLine]For[,i<m,i++,If[Mod[\
m,i]\[Equal]0,Print[ToString@m<>\" is not a Prime \"];Break[]]];\
\[IndentingNewLine]If[i\[Equal]m,Print[ToString@m<>\" is a Prime \"]]\
\[IndentingNewLine]]";
ToExpression[st]
prime[29]
prime[30]

29 is a Prime 

30 is not a Prime
```

Comment: There is a warning when I copied your code.
`Warning: comma encountered with no adjacent expression. The 
expression will be treated as Null.`

Comment: @kile That comes from your code.  Namely, `For[,i<m....`.